# System stops responding while read a large text file using stramreader & pass them in to a data grid

Tags: c#

System stops responding while read a large text file using stramreader & pass them in to a data grid.

Appreciates your support to resolve this issue.

here is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    button2.Enabled = false;
    button3.Enabled = false;
    int lno = 0;
    try 
    {
        char[]seps = {',','\n','\r','','','┐',' '};

        StreamReader read = new StreamReader(fd.FileName);
        line = read.ReadToEnd();
        String[]spLine = line.Split(seps);
        for (int i = 0; i < spLine.Length; i++) 
        {       
            if ((prv.Equals("1:")) || (prv.Equals("1-")))
            {
                lno++;
                display.AppendText(" 1 : " + spLine[i]);
                display.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(lno, "1", spLine[i]);
            }
            else if (prv.Equals("1")) 
            {
                lno++;
                display.AppendText(" 1 : " + spLine[i + 1]);
                display.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(lno, "1", spLine[i + 1]);
            }
            else if (prv.Equals("2")) 
            {
                lno++;
                display.AppendText(" 2 : " + spLine[i + 1]);
                display.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(lno, "2", spLine[i + 1]);
            }
            prv = spLine[i].Trim();
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {}

    button2.Enabled = true;
    button3.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Use a BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 0):

If you process lots of data in the UI thread, you are **blocking the windows event loop**, which prevents it painting, and causes it to report as unresponsive. You should do such processing on a worker thread, and then switch back to the UI thread (either at the end, or in batches - not for every row) to perform the UI updates like adding rows to grids.

Yes, this makes it more complicated. Yes, it is necessary if you don't want it to show as unresponsive.